# How to achieve the same but with way lesser code (Or using some of Kotlin's extension functions)

Tags: android, kotlin

I've this list. Let's call it milestones. So the list looks like this.

```
val milestones = List<Milestone>()
```

And Milestone class looks like this

```
data class Milestone {
    val isCompleted: Boolean
}
```

Now what I've to check here is once I get the list of milestones I need to know if all the milestones are completed. Basically I wanna write a function which takes in this milestone list and returns true if all milestones are completed, or false if not.

I've written the same like this

```
fun areMilestonesCompleted(milestones: List<Milestone>) {
    var completed = true

    for (milestone in milestones) {
        if (!milestone.isCompleted) {
            completed = false
            break
        }
    }
    return completed
}
```

This works, but I'm pretty sure there will be some prebuilt extension function in Kotlin which can achieve the same with far lesser code. So looking for some good advice over here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```kotlin
fun areMilestonesCompleted(milestones: List<Milestone>) = milestones.all { it.isCompleted }
```